# How do I get the default mail client using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to get the default mail client from Powershell script.

I know that this information is stored in the windows registry: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command` but the `HKCR` is not available by default from Powershell.

Do you know any way to access the above key or to get the default mail client in another way?

Thanks in advance,
Qinto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is [an amalgamation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`.

So you can do it as follows:

```
$node = Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Classes\mailto\shell\open\command
if (!$node) { $node = Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Classes\mailto\shell\open\command }
$MailClient = $node.'(default)'
```

Comment: Did you mean in the second line HKLM instead of HKCU?

Comment: @Joey must have meant HKLM.